# Is returning declval UB if the template is never called outside of unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming

I am writing some metafunctions, and I had the idea to write them using C++17's if constexpr combined with deduced return type. Here is an example :

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename TupleType, std::size_t I = 0, typename... ReturnData>
constexpr auto filterImpl()
{
    if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size_v<TupleType>)
    {
        using Type = std::tuple_element_t<I, TupleType>;

        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>)
            return filterImpl<TupleType, I + 1, ReturnData..., Type>();
        else
            return filterImpl<TupleType, I + 1, ReturnData...>();
    }
    else
        return std::declval<std::tuple<ReturnData...>>();
}
template<typename Tuple>
using FilterTuple = decltype(filterImpl<Tuple>());

//std::tuple<int, float>
using MyTuple = FilterTuple<std::tuple<int, std::string, float, int*>>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyTuple t{ 3, 5.f };

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you could probably use a simpler pattern for this problem, but this just a basic example of what I want to do.

This code compiles on msvc, but doesn't on onlinegdb.
Which one is right?
Is using declval this way authorized?
Should I even write my metafunctions like that, or should I go back to template classes?

(I think that, if there is a way to do so, the more complex metafunctions could end up easier to read this way)

A [mcve](https://godbolt.org/z/3Px3sbTTq):

```
#include <utility>

template<bool b>
constexpr auto evil()
{
    if constexpr (b)
        return 0;
    else
        return std::declval<int>();
}

template<bool b>
using Test = decltype(evil<b>());

int main()
{
    Test<false> t{};
}
```

Comment: is it valid to have inconsistent return types for `auto` return type? because it seems you do and I thought it was not valid.

Comment: @Afshin only one branch of `constexpr if` is evaluated at the same time. You can think of it as if it was seperate functions each containing only one of the branches

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yea, I just noticed after some testing. But it is somehow strange, because `template <typename T> constexpr auto foo() { if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<T>) return 1; return "no"; }` gives an error while `template <typename T> constexpr auto foo() { if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<T>) return 1; else return "no"; }` is correct. In both cases return is determined but without `else` it generates an error.

Comment: @Afshin it is only the branches of the `constexpr if` that are discarded

Comment: @Afshin: `if constexpr` doesn’t discard return statements that are simply unreachable because of a preceding return statement, but it will remove the `else` as appropriate.

Comment: @Afshin consider to post it as question. Code in comments is extremely hard to read. I was staring at it for a minute to realize that the two are actually different. And anyhow, comments are not for q&as, thats what questions and answers are for ;)

Comment: @Afshin This is because the `else` is part of the `if constexpr`. So if you do not use the `else` the second return is still active (although unreachable) so it's like compiling `return 1; return "no";`

Comment: It hinges on whether `std::declval` is odr-used here. Which in turn hinges on whether it's a potentially evaluated expression. Which I think it is: "An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 8) or a subexpression thereof." A body of the function is not a subexpression of the function call expression. So I think the `std::declval<std::tuple<ReturnData...>>()` is in fact odr-used when the function template is instantiated in a way that reaches that branch.

Comment: @AlexandreS. I added a MCVE that removes the practical work you are doing, and isolates just the declval problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you must **instantiate** the function template to determine its return type, there is a function that **odr-uses** `std::declval<…>`, so the program is ill-formed.  MSVC is in error to accept it (without a warning), although it could be argued that this rule oughtn’t require a diagnostic to allow the obvious implementation strategy of just failing to provide a **definition** for`std::declval`.